# Issue with Control MouseLeave event

Tags: c#, events, user-controls

It appears that when I am using the `MouseLeave` event to perform an action, if the user leaves the `Control` fast enough, it will actually skip the `MouseLeave` event..

The user will be out of the `control` and the `MouseLeave` event wasn't called. Now, I don't know if there is a way to fix this, or if there is a better event to use. I basically have a `UserControl` that has a `Combobox` in it. When the other scrolls over the `UserControl`, the `ComboBox` appears (works everytime), however, when they user leaves that `Control` to go to another one, it may or may not make the ComboBox`.Visible = false. It seems to depend on the rate of the Cursor moving.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Have you registered the event handler?

Comment: @Oded Yes, the event DOES fire when you move out of the control SLOWLY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime ago it happened to me! I had to hook mouse events using PInvoke, and do all the logic myself.

The following article contains details on how to hook mouse events.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

After you manage to hook the events, you will need to do the logic of calculating the absolute position of your control, and tell whether mouse pointer is in or out. Then you need to keep track of the in/out changes, and it is all.

Long way to go... I would say this is an overkill. But if you really need it, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse leave event will call when you leave the control . I think you missed to registered it.

```
 private void comboBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

You can use comboboxleave event this will call when you leave this control and that is you are expecting i think :)
Don't forget to register the event first

Comment: private void comboBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine it happens when the mouse is captured: [WM_MOUSELEAVE not being generated when left mouse button is held](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283428/wm-mouseleave-not-being-generated-when-left-mouse-button-is-held)